# I caught an IOException while accepting client connections on server socket.Now what?

Tags: java, sockets, io, ioexception, serversocket

What does an `IOException` indicate when it is thrown from [ServerSocket#accept](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29)?
What I mean is: if I have a loop accepting connection it will be blocked here:

`Socket client = serverSocket.accept();`

If I `catch` an `IOException` during accept does this mean that I should close the server socket i.e. it is something severe or I e.g. log the exception and go back accepting connections in `serverSocket.accept()` like nothing happened?I.e. the server socket is full functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get these from running out of file descriptors. Another possibility is SocketTimeoutException, if you have set a timeout and it expires. Another is that the server socket got closed asynchronously. Only the last of these is necessarily fatal.

Comment: So you suggest to try to reaccept unless I see that the socket has been closed?

Comment: @Cratylus Please let's not talk about reconnecting when we should be talking about accepting connections.

Comment: Ok!So I should just go back into `serverSocket.accept()` unless in the catch of `IOException` the `serverSocket.isClosed()` returns `true`?

Comment: It depends. If you've run out of descriptors you have to close one. If you got a timeout you need to consider why you set it.

Comment: When you say descriptors you mean client sockets?

Comment: When I say descriptors I mean descriptors, actually. File descriptors. See my answer. They include but are not limited to sockets.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand this.A client socket is a file descriptor right?So the file descriptors of the existing clients does not close when closing the server socket?Is this what you mean?They stay reserved by OS?

Comment: It's not just what i mean, it is what I have already said twice, and what tigran has also told you already.

Comment: I didn't know this.So clients just remain hanging?Ok

Comment: @Cratylus One of these days you must learn not to put words into other people's mouths. You've done it several times already here, mistakenly, and you've just done it again. I didn't say that; it doesn't follow from anything I have said; and it isn't true. The clients will keep executing. Their connections are completely unaffected by closing the ServerSocket.

Comment: Putting words is not my intention.It is just that the information is very "compressed" and I am trying to understand it.So by 1)clients are connected to server and 2) close of the ServerSocket doesn't release any descriptors what is the correct inference?

Comment: That is a correct *restatement* of what has already been said. No inference is required, and no 'putting words' either.

Comment: @Cratylus - when you call `ServerSocket.accept()`, you get a `Socket` instance back. That `Socket` is independent of the `ServerSocket` that returned it. If you close the `ServerSocket` you do *not* close any `Socket`s that it returned.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen only one case where accept was throwing an exception: too many open files. Depending on your aplication, you may wait and go into accept again, close try the loop of close/bind/accept or fail. We have implemented the both strategies an at the and it always endup with fail. Again, if your clients are short living, you may recover. Our clients long living...

Comment: 1)`too many open files` Do you mean too many client sockets?2)Did not understand what are the 2 strategies you suggest.a)go back to accept? b) close and recreate socket? something else?

Comment: 1. yes, we have too many connections ~8000 and in node not configured correctly the you are in a trouble. 2. right. this is what we do shortly wait and try accept again and recreate socket.

Comment: If you run out of file descriptors you have to close something before you retry, unless you just want the same error immediately again. And again. And again. And just closing the ServerSocket and opening a new one doesn't release any descriptors.

Comment: as I said, in our case we fail, but last hope (may be some one just disconnected) logic is there

Comment: @EJP:If I close the `ServerSocket` won't the client sockets close as well?I suppose this is what you mean by releashing descriptors.

Comment: @Cratylus I repeat: 'closing the ServerSocket and opening a new one doesn't release any descriptors'.

Comment: closing serverSocket does not closes exising connections.

Comment: @tigran:I didn't know this.So clients remain hanging?

Comment: @Cratylus That's not what he said. I don't know where you get these strange ideas, or how you form these 'so' inferences that don't follow from anything that had been said.

Comment: @Cratylus client remain connected.

Comment: @tigran:Connected to what if the server socket is closed?

Comment: @Cratylus Connected to whatever they were connected to when it was still open. They are unaffected by closing it. Nothing happens to them. They stay connected. They don't hang. How many times, and how many ways, do you need to be told?

Comment: yes, you will not accept new clients, but old one will stay conncted. The accept method returns a socket connected with the client. ServerSocket is there to bind and accept only.

Comment: @EJP:I think I am missing background info.In my mind the server socket was directly related to client connections.So I was wrong.They are connected to something else I guess and remain connected there even is the server socket closes

Comment: @Cratylus That is exactly what three different people have already told you, about six times. You aren't 'missing' any background information here: you are *inventing* it when it doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

From the API doc:

> IOException  if an I/O error occurs when waiting for a connection.

This means that if exception was thrown here something is going bad. For example port is busy, network adapter is unavailable etc. So, try to wait a little bit and reconnect. If this happens again, nothing to do. You cannot connect to chosen port.

Change port? Change address? Close application with error message? :(

Comment: `So, try to wait a little bit and reconnect.`What do you mean by reconnect?Also `port is busy` would be a `BindException` not an `IOException`

Comment: You've misunderstood both the Javadoc and the question. It is about ServerSocket.accept(). Changing ports etc does not solve this problem.